# Difference between hosts: localhost and connection: local

Tags: ansible

Running the task on the localhost can be achieved in different ways.

I do not understand if there is a difference between the way the two tasks are executed below or if they are exactly the same thing.

If so, `fakehost` in the second task is just a placeholder, right?

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: localhost without explicit connection
    boto3_facts:

- hosts: fakehost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: runner host using local connection
    boto3_facts:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: ***"fakehost in the second task is just a placeholder, right?"***

A: Yes. It's just an [alias](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-aliases) (placeholder).

Run the playbook with *`-vvvv to enable connection debugging`*. You'll see

```
verbosity: 4
connection: smart
```

[Connection plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection.html#plugin-list) says nothing about *`smart`*. It's necessary to see the [source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible).

[ansible/lib/ansible/config/base.yml](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/config/base.yml#L1117) says

```yaml
DEFAULT_TRANSPORT:
  name: Connection plugin
  default: smart
  description: "Default connection plugin to use, the 'smart' option will toggle
                between 'ssh' and 'paramiko' depending on controller OS and ssh
                versions"
```

The next step would be to dig the source and find out how ssh and paramiko handle localhost. (Wild guess, do nothing and use connection *`local`*).

---

Connection plugin [local](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/local.html) says

> *"The remote user is ignored, the user with which the ansible CLI was executed is used instead."*

Let's add a *`remote_user`* to the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: admin
  tasks:
    - name: localhost without explicit connection
      debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
          - "{{ ansible_user }}"

- hosts: fakehost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  remote_user: admin
  tasks:
    - name: runner host using local connection
      debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
          - "{{ ansible_user }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> whoami
vlado
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml

ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - localhost
  - vlado

ok: [fakehost] => 
  msg:
  - fakehost
  - vlado
```

The inventory was

```
shell> cat hosts
fakehost
```

I'd conclude that Ansible is "smart" enough to use the *`local`* connection plugin in both cases.